Optimization of code for the longest loop problem in undirected graph
The following code can solve smaller graphs, but the graph size that needs to be solved is relatively large, with 61 vertices and 1741 edges. I need to find the maximum length of its loop, which uses a hash table to store the accessed paths, but it will use a lot of memory and out of heap.
Hope to provide some optimization or ideas
class j20016 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new j20016();
    }

    j20016() {
        // read();
        test();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            solve(i, 0, "");
        }
        System.out.println(ans);
        System.out.print(times);
    }

    void solve(int curNode, int len, String path) {
        times++;
        if(len == N-1) return;

        if(path.contains(String.valueOf(curNode)))
        {
            ans = Math.max(ans, len);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if(arr[curNode][i] == 1)
            {
                solve(i, len+1, path+ (i - 1));
            }
        }
    }

    void read()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        N = sc.nextInt();
        arr = new int[N][N];
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            arr[a-1][b-1] = 1;
            arr[b-1][a-1] = 1;
        }
    }
    void test()
    {
        String test =
                "6 10\n" +
                "1 2\n" +
                "1 3\n" +
                "1 5\n" +
                "2 3\n" +
                "2 5\n" +
                "2 6\n" +
                "3 4\n" +
                "3 5\n" +
                "3 6\n" +
                "4 6";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(test);
        N = sc.nextInt();
        arr = new int[N][N];
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            int a = sc.nextInt();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            arr[a-1][b-1] = 1;
            arr[b-1][a-1] = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    int[][] arr;
    int N; // 节点数
    int ans = 0;
    int times = 0;
}

6 10  // 6 is numbers of nodes, 10 is  The number of lines to be entered later
1 2 // node 1 and node 2 is connected
1 3
1 5
2 3
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 6


If by "loop" you mean "cycle", your problem is equivalent to finding a Hamiltonian Cycle in an undirected graph, which is an NP-hard problem: Basically, no one knows an algorithm that solves all cases efficiently.
